# Create a single button which can trigger two actions and changes it's title?

Tags: ios, xcode, button, uibutton, core-motion

```
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake( 10, 80, 100, 30 );
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];
[button setTitle: @"Start" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(start_Accel) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle: @"Stop" forState: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(stop_Accel) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[view addSubview:button];
```

I want to create a button that can start and stop accelerometer updates as user presses it, But it's title too should change from start to stop and also it should continues until user reset everything by an anoterh button, but i have no idea of getting it done, except the following code, But it doesnt change the title and call stop action?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manage the state of the button in some kind of was eg. with a @property and use just one action:

in you .h

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL startStopButtonIsActive;
```

in your .m

```
@synthesize startStopButtonIsActive = _startStopButtonIsActive;

 ....

- (void)viewDidLoad {
       [button addTarget:self action:@selector(startStopButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      // other stuff
}

- (void)startStopButtonPressed {
    if (startStopButtonIsActive) {
        self.startStopButtonIsActive = !self.startStopButtonIsActive  //toggle!
        // do your stuff here
    } else {
        self.startStopButtonIsActive = !self.startStopButtonIsActive  //toggle!
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, In this case haw can i change the text of the button? Do i need to define button in .h as @property(retain) IBOutlet UIButton *someButton;
and then use  [somebutton setTitle: @"Start" forState: UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Hi. Can i know the reason why you edited your answer with @synthesize startStopButtonIsActive = _startStopButtonIsActive;
and also i was able to implement the code to change the title, Thank you!

Comment: i edited it to because just an property alone is not sufficient. You seemed to figure it out to ad the synthesize by yourself but not everybody will. So it is more clear for everyone who reads it. The reason for adding = _propertyVar is for renaming the backing iVar of the property. This has the advantage that you can easily see if you set the iVar via its getter or directly. Rule of thumb is you should use getter and setters: self.button

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

Add only one target to the button - such that the target method that has awareness of the current state.  Make sure you have a colon in the selector so it receives the sender as an argument of the method. i.e. `startOrStopAccel:` versus `startOrStopAccel`.

You can have that one target method call either `start_Accel` or `stop_Accel` depending on the state.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    //...
    //...
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake( 10, 80, 100, 30 );
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];
    [button setTitle: @"Start" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(startOrStopAccel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view addSubview:button];
}

-(void)startOrStopAccel:(UIButton*)sender {
    if ([sender.title isEqualToString:@"Start"]) {
        [sender setTitle: @"Stop" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [self start_Accel];
    }
    else {
        [sender setTitle: @"Start" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [self stop_Accel];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There should only be one target in this case, and you should have it pass the button along with the action by adding an argument to the signature:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(accelButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// the interface being:
-(void) accelButtonPressed:(UIButton *) sender;
```

Inside that method, you can check state and change state, as well as the properties of the button (which is referenced in 'sender'.

Answer (score 0):

first you want declare your button and an integer variable in .h file.

then ,

```
intergervariable=0;

    button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];
    [button setTitle: @"Start" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(start_Accel) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view addSubview:button];

after that inside the start_Accel function check like this


if(intergervariable==0)
{
intergervariable=1; 
[button setTitle: @"Start" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
else if(intergervariable==1)
{
intergervariable=0;
 [button setTitle: @"Stop" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```